# Assign a range to an array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Everything I find says this is a quick and easy way to assign a range of values to an array.

I get an error when I try to access the array.

> Subscript out of range.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub assign_arr_from_range()
    Dim myArr() As Variant
    myArr = Range("A1:D1").Value
    MsgBox (myArr(3))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `myArr = Range("...").Value` method always creates a two-dimensional array, regardless of whether the range is a row, a column, or an area.
- To access (read/update) a specific item, you should use myArr(1, x) instead of myArr(x).
- However, if you prefer using myArr(x), you can implement option 2 as shown below.

```
Option Explicit
Sub assign_arr_from_range()
    
    Dim myArr(), myArr2() 
    myArr = Range("A1:D1").Value
    MsgBox (myArr(1, 3))
    
    ' Option 2
    myArr2 = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range("A1:D1").Value))
    MsgBox (myArr2(3))
    
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [WorksheetFunction.Transpose method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.transpose?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm137117)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)